# Haystack cannot connect to Solr

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

I have an existing site where search worked fine until a few days ago. Now, no matter what keyword is used, no results are returned. I followed [Haystack's troubleshooting guide](http://docs.haystacksearch.org/dev/debugging.html#no-results-found-on-the-web-page) and get the following error:

```
Failed to query Solr using '*:*': Failed to connect to server ...
```

But, Solr is definitely running, and I can access it at the URL given in the error message. **I even ran the same query Haystack attempted to run and got a proper response.**

Given that Solr is running and no code has changed on the site, I'm at a complete loss as to why Haystack suddenly thinks it's not there. Any ideas?

Comment: give a try yourself with a browser, e.g. http://solr-ip:solr-port/core-name/select/?q=*:*

Comment: Can you provide more information?
What version of haystack are you using?
if you print out HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL, what does it say?
What about the HAYSTACK_SITECONF?